# multiple linq orderby not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have multiple `OrderBy` but only the first order column is working

```
public static List<vwData> GetAllData(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Date;
    DateTime dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date;


    var entities = new DataEntities();
    var query = from c in entities.vwData
                let eventDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate)
                orderby c.EventCreateDate ascending, c.StartDateTime ascending
                where eventDate >= dtStart && eventDate <= dtEndDate
                select c;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample input data and expected output?

Comment: Your code seems OK, Why you think that only first order is working?

Answer (score 0):

Orderby should be after condition check and default ordering is ascending

```
var query = from c in entities.vwData
            let eventDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate)
            where eventDate >= dtStart && eventDate <= dtEndDate
            orderby c.EventCreateDate, c.StartDateTime
            select c;
return query.ToList();
```

OR

Using `Linq`, we can do as follows

```
var query = entities.vwData.Where(i =>
{
    var eventDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.EventCreateDate);
    if (eventDate >= dtStart && eventDate <= dtEndDate)
        return true;

    return false;
})
.OrderBy(j => j.EventCreateDate)
.ThenBy(k => k.StartDateTime)
.Select(m => m);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Query expression syntax does not contains `thenby` clause

Comment: hi Siva, i have got an error when i using your linq solution it said that A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `ThenBy`:

```
public static List<vwData> GetAllData(string startDate, string endDate)
{
  DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Date;
  DateTime dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date;


  var entities = new DataEntities();
  var query = from c in entities.vwData
            let eventDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate)
            orderby c.EventCreateDate ascending
            thenby c.StartDateTime ascending
            where eventDate >= dtStart && eventDate <= dtEndDate
            select c;
  return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Query expression syntax does not contains `thenby` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try following query. It will help you:

```
    var query = entities.vwData.Where(i => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.OrderDate) >= dtStart  && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.OrderDate) <= dtEndDate )
        .OrderBy(j => j.EventCreateDate)
        .ThenBy(k => k.StartDateTime)
        .Select(m => m);

   return query.ToList();
```

Comment: still not ordering the second order